# How to compute the minimum of the difference of a vector of values?

Tags: vector, rust

How to compute the minimum difference of a vector in Rust?

The below code:

```
fn main() {
    let vector: Vec<f64> = vec![1.025, 1.028, 1.03, 1.05, 1.051];

    let mut result: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..vector.len() - 1 {
        result.push(vector[i] - vector[i + 1]);
    }
    println!("{:?}", result);

    let minimum = std::cmp::min(&result[0], &result[1]);
    println!("{}", minimum)
}
```

Results in:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
10 |     let minimum = std::cmp::min(&result[0], &result[1]);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Ord` is not implemented for `f64`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::Ord` for `&f64`
   = note: required by `std::cmp::min`
```

The challenges are:

- [no comparison between f32/f64 types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40922)
- only two values can be compared at any one time; how can I compute all values? Can a fold be used or does it have to be a macro?
- what is a memory efficient way to perform the difference over the vector? For example, creating a range and iterating over a vector (`for i in 0..5 { vector[i] }`) is more expensive than creating an iterator over the vector itself `for i in &vector`.

Comment: SO favors one question at a time; may I recommend eliding the "formatting" question since all others are tied together?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, I removed the formatting point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use iterators!

On slices, it is possible to use the [`windows()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) method to get the consecutive pairs of elements. In your case, `vector.windows(2)` will yield: `[1.025, 1.028]`, `[1.028, 1.03]`, `[1.03, 1.05]`, and finally `[1.05, 1.051]`.

This an iterator, so you can apply a transformation on it. In your case, I would suggest [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map), to map each pair to the difference between the two elements of the pair: `.map(|slice| slice[0] - slice[1])`. And maybe take the absolute difference, using `(slice[0] - slice[1]).abs()`.

This is still an iterator, so finally you can apply [`min_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by) which will only yield the minimum of all elements. Floats only implement `PartialOrd`<sup>1</sup>, so: `.min_by(|x, y| x.partial_cmp(y).unwrap())`.

Putting it altogether [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=deb2b8cdffb4c03755ad9b296ae21b65&version=stable&mode=debug):

```
fn main() {
    let vector = vec![1.025_f64, 1.028, 1.03, 1.05, 1.051];

    let minimum =
        vector.windows(2)
            .map(|slice| (slice[0] - slice[1]).abs())
            .min_by(|x, y| x.partial_cmp(y).unwrap());

    println!("{:?}", minimum);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *As seen here, floats CAN be compared. Due to the presence of NaNs however, the result is `Option<Ordering>`. In this case, assuming that there is no NaN in the input data, I just used `unwrap` to get to the underlying ordering; if a NaN sneaks in, it will panic.*

Comment: Is this a correct trait implementation of your code for the vector type?: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d3dbe1cb49a0ec1295eb7ef91714f4a3&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: @Greg: It can be simplified a bit (see https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ebf266eb481f0a6b58476849dcbb099d&version=stable&mode=debug) => no need to clone the option. I find the name `minimum` a bit confusing though, to be honest, I'd stick to `minimum_difference`; I would expect `minimum` to refer to the smallest element, not the smallest difference between elements :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
let v = vec![1.025f64, 1.028, 1.03, 1.05, 1.051];
let min = (0..v.len() - 1)
    .map(|i| (v[i] - v[i + 1]).abs())
    .min_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());  // panic on `NaN`

println!("{:?}", min);
```

This code doesn't use a temporary vector to hold the differences. Instead it computes everything on the fly thanks to lazy iterators. Also note that I uses [`abs()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.abs) to compute the absolute difference (this is probably what you wanted).

To find the minimum, `Iterator` offers a range of methods: `min()`, `min_by_key` and `min_by`. I used the later to deal with the problem of uncomparable floats. My code just panics if we encounter a `NaN` value. This might be OK for your use case, but you might expect `NaN` values and want to deal with the error.

The resulting `min` variable is an `Option<f64>` which is `None` if the vector has length 1. If the vector has length 0, it panics when indexing `v[i + 1]`.

About your "floats are inaccurate" problem: Yes, that's true. The only way to really solve this problem is by using a arbitrary precision type. There are probably a couple of crates offering such types. But this isn't really in the scope of this question anymore.

Comment: Say your data points are measurements of the speed of a car spaced evenly in time. Minimum difference tells you how good your brakes are. Minimum absolute difference tells you nothing so useful